# How to work forEachLimit in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

What is the working of `forEachLimit` in node js.

```
async.forEachLimit(array,5,(item,callback)=>{
    //something
},(err)=>{
    //end of loop
})
```

Comment: Can you give more context to your question?

Comment: soundslikeodd i won kwon what is the use of 5 in forEachLimit.

Comment: It is the concurrency limit. How many of these async requests will be allowed to run at the same time. The others will be queued up until another completes if you request more than the limit specified.

Comment: thanks rasmeister...

Comment: @Nodejs please edit your question to reflect the information in you provided in your comment.

Answer (score 2):

It works almost like `async.forEach` except that it doesn’t run a task for all items immediately in parallel. The concurrency value is an integer that tells Async how many tasks are allowed to run simultaneously. Let’s say that our database only allows 5 connections at a time, then we simply change our code to:

```
app.delete('/messages/:messageIds', function(req, res, next) {
    var messageIds = req.params.messageIds.split(',');
    // `5` is the `concurrency` argument here
    // ----------------------------↴
    async.forEachLimit(messageIds, 5, function(messageId, callback) {
        db.delete('messages', messageId, callback);
    }, function(err) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json({
            success: true,
            message: messageIds.length+' message(s) was deleted.'
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument in `forEachLimit()` is the max limit of async operations.

From the [documentation](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachLimit):

> limit - The maximum number of async operations at a time.

Also, from the [code comments](https://caolan.github.io/async/eachLimit.js.html):

`@param {number} limit - The maximum number of async operations at a time.`